# How can I access the last message which is sent to a processor in MPI?

Tags: mpi

I am using a master-worker structure using Message Passing Interface (MPI) but whenever I call Receive function, instead of receiving the messages in the order of sending sequence, I need to receive the last message sent from the master to the each processor and ignore the previous ones!

My question is that if there is any way that we can access each processor's buffer and pick the last message in the queue?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't just peer into the queue; but you can test to see if more messages are present with [MPI_Probe](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Probe.3.php) or [MPI_Iprobe](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Iprobe.3.php), and while there are more messages present, keep receiving and discarding the old data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import time

def waiter(comm, sendTask):
    # wait for messages to be present
    while not comm.Iprobe(source=sendTask, tag=1):
        time.sleep(1)

    # read all messages while more are available, discarding old
    while comm.Iprobe(source=sendTask, tag=1):
        lastMsg = comm.recv(source=sendTask, tag=1)

    if lastMsg is None:
        print "No messages pending"
    else:
        print "Last message was ", lastMsg

    comm.Barrier() 

def sender(comm, waitTask):
    for msgno in range(5):
        print "sending: ", msgno
        comm.send(msgno, dest=waitTask, tag=1)

    print "sending: ", -1
    comm.send(-1, dest=waitTask, tag=1)

    comm.Barrier() 

if __name__== "__main__":
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    sendTask = 1
    waitTask = 0
    if comm.rank == waitTask:
        waiter(comm, sendTask)
    elif comm.rank == sendTask:
        sender(comm, waitTask)
    else:
        comm.Barrier()
```

Running gives

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./readall.py
sending:  0
sending:  1
sending:  2
sending:  3
sending:  4
sending:  -1
Last message was  -1
```